# Python 3 - Problema de conversão CSV para Excel com output em lista

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, pdf, csv

Boa tarde. Estou enfrentando um problema durante a conversão de um arquivo CSV para um arquivo Excel, via openpyxl. A estrutura do código tem por objetivo converter um PDF em Excel, e colar as informações do PDF em uma Sheet de uma planilha de Excel já pré-formatada.

O que tentei:

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import string
import csv
    

pdfFileObj=open(r".\pasta_460\pdf_460.pdf",'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

paginas_pdf = []
for page in pdfReader.pages:
    ddd = page.extractText()
    paginas_pdf.append(ddd)

df = pd.DataFrame(paginas_pdf)
df.to_csv(r".\pasta_460\pdf_em_csv_460.csv",encoding='utf-8')

book = load_workbook(r".\teste_template_planilha.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r".\teste_template_460_modelada.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet12')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet12', startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```

Até funcionou e gerou a planilha com a Sheet12 contendo os dados que eu propus, porém, os dados saem todos em uma linha única do Excel, eu acredito que seja porque os dados estão em CSV guardados dentro de uma lista (paginas_pdf), mas não estou achando solução para este problema.

Gostaria que os dados saíssem na Sheet12 linha a linha, ou seja, que o delimitador ":" quebre a informação e coloque linha a linha.

Segue um df.head(10) - O arquivo só fica com 3 linhas -
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Para salvar para excel isso seria o suficiente `df.to_excel("output.xlsx")` apagando todas as linhas de `book = ` para baixo.

Comment: Mesmo usando ```df.to_excel("output.xlsx")``` os dados saem todos em uma linha única. Já tentei ```df.replace('\n', ' ')``` e também mantem a estrutura de linhas únicas, como se fosse uma array. A questão do código de ```book =``` para baixo é na intensão de criar a planilha na mesma planilha que eu indiquei como modelo.

Comment: Execute df.head() e atualiza o post

Comment: @PauloMarques, veja se com as imagens fica mais fácil identificar o problema. Agradeço a atenção

Comment: Antes da linha `paginas_pdf.append(ddd)` acrescente `items = ddd.split("\n")` depois substitua `paginas_pdf.append(ddd)` por `paginas_pdf += items`. Deve resolver.

Comment: Você é um gênio! ahahha
Obrigado pela ajuda. A solução funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentando a solução sugerida no comentário

```
import PyPDF2
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
import string
import csv
    

pdfFileObj=open(r".\pasta_460\pdf_460.pdf",'rb')
pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFileObj)

paginas_pdf = []
for page in pdfReader.pages:
    ddd = page.extractText()
    items = ddd.split("\n")   # linha adicionada
    paginas_pdf += items      # linha adicionada
    # paginas_pdf.append(ddd) <- linha retirada

df = pd.DataFrame(paginas_pdf)
df.to_csv(r".\pasta_460\pdf_em_csv_460.csv",encoding='utf-8')

book = load_workbook(r".\teste_template_planilha.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r".\teste_template_460_modelada.xlsx", engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet12')
df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet12', startrow=1, startcol=1, header=False, index=False)
writer.save()
```